# EditorFor Tag Helper doesn't render validation attributes when using FluentValidator

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac, fluentvalidation, tag-helpers

I have a simple form like this which makes use of the @Html.EditorFor extension:

```
<form method="post">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.SystemSettings.EmailFromAddress)
    <submit-button title="Save"></submit-button>
</form>
```

I want to take advantage of .NET Core's tag helpers so that my form looks like this instead:

```
<form method="post">
    <editor asp-for="SystemSettings.EmailFromAddress"/>
    <submit-button title="Save"></submit-button>
</form>
```

I also eventually would like to have my own custom tag helpers so I can do something like this instead:

```
<text-box asp-for="SystemSettings.EmailFromAddress"></text-box>
```

I have a *string* template which gets rendered by the @Html.EditorFor extension:

```
@model string
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model" class="m-b-none"></label>
    <span asp-description-for="@Model" class="help-block m-b-none small m-t-none"></span>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input asp-for="@Model" class="form-control" />
        <partial name="_ValidationIcon" />
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model" class="validation-message"></span>
</div>
```

To do that, I saw someone implemented an **EditorTagHelper**, which looks like this:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("editor", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag,
    Attributes = ForAttributeName)]
public class EditorTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private readonly IHtmlHelper _htmlHelper;

    private const string ForAttributeName = "asp-for";
    private const string TemplateAttributeName = "asp-template";

    [HtmlAttributeName(ForAttributeName)]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }


    [HtmlAttributeName(TemplateAttributeName)]
    public string Template { get; set; }

    [ViewContext]
    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public EditorTagHelper(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        _htmlHelper = htmlHelper;
    }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (output == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));

        if (!output.Attributes.ContainsName(nameof(Template)))
        {
            output.Attributes.Add(nameof(Template), Template);
        }

        output.SuppressOutput();

        (_htmlHelper as IViewContextAware).Contextualize(ViewContext);

        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(_htmlHelper.Editor(For.Name, Template));

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

When I use the EditorTagHelper though, it seems to be missing the unobtrusive Javascript validation attributes:

Using **@Html.EditorFor**, this gets rendered:

```
<input class="form-control valid" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="Email From Address cannot be empty" id="SystemSettings_EmailFromAddress" name="SystemSettings.EmailFromAddress" value="whatever@test.com" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="SystemSettings_EmailFromAddress-error">
```

It's got the data-val attributes so client-side validation gets applied.

When I use the **EditorTagHelper** instead, this gets rendered:

```
<input class="form-control valid" type="text" id="SystemSettings_EmailFromAddress" name="SystemSettings.EmailFromAddress" value="whatever@test.com" aria-invalid="false">
```

The unobtrusive validation attributes are not being applied. I am using FluentValidation and I have specified an AbstractValidator like this:

```
public class SystemSettingsValidator : AbstractValidator<SystemSettings>
{
    public SystemSettingsValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.EmailFromAddress).NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Email From Address cannot be empty");
    }
}
```

I found that if I removed the AbstractorValidator and simply added a [Required] attribute to my model property the validation then works properly. This suggests that there is something wrong with FluentValidation. Perhaps there is a configuration issue.

I am using Autofac dependency injection to scan my assemblies and register validator types:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load(assembly))
    .Where(t => t.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IValidator<>)))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .PropertiesAutowired()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

This seems to work fine. In case it wasn't fine, I also tried registering the validators from the fluent validation options like this:

```
.AddFluentValidation(fv =>
{
    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblies(new List<Assembly>
        {Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), Assembly.Load(nameof(Entities))});
})
```

This also seemed to be fine.

One thing to note is that an earlier problem I had was that using Autofac assembly scanning was breaking the application when tag helpers were included. I added a filter to ensure that tag helpers are not included when registering these dependencies, e.g.

```
builder.RegisterAutowiredAssemblyInterfaces(Assembly.Load(Web))
    .Where(x => !x.Name.EndsWith("TagHelper"));
```

I have uploaded a working sample of the code here: https://github.com/ciaran036/coresample2

Navigate to the [Settings Page](https://github.com/ciaran036/coresample2/blob/master/Web/Pages/Settings/Index.cshtml) to see the field I am trying to validate.

This issue also appears to affect view components.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify: You say "I found that if I removed the AbstractorValidator and simply added a [Required] attribute to my model property the validation then works properly." <-- is this when using your EditorTagHelper or in the @Html.EditorFor call?

Comment: When using the [Required] attribute, the validation works for both the editor tag helper and the @Html.EditorFor extension method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is in the tag helper, in that it uses `IHtmlHelper.Editor` rather than `IHtmlHelper<TModel>.EditorFor` to generate the HTML content. They are not quite the same.

As you point out FluentValidation injects the validation attributes as you'd expect for `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SystemSettings.EmailFromAddress)`. However for `@Html.Editor("SystemSettings.EmailFromAddress")`, which is what your custom tag helper is doing, FluentValidation doesn't inject the validation attributes. So that rules out the tag helper itself and moves the problem to the `Editor` invocation.

I also noticed that `Editor` doesn't resolve `<label asp-for` (or the other `<span asp-description-for` tag helper you're using) so that suggests it's not a FluentValidation specific issue.

I wasn't able to replicate your success with the `Required` attribute for the custom tag helper/`Editor` - the `Required` attribute only injected the validation attributes when using `EditorFor`.

The internals for `Editor` and `EditorFor` are similar but with a key difference, the way they resolve the `ModelExplorer` instance used to generate the HTML content differs and I suspect this is the problem. See below for these differences.

[image: Editor vs EditorFor ModelExplorer]

Things like `PropertyName` set to null and `Metadata.Property` not being set for `Editor`, but set to `EmailFromAddress` and `SystemSettings.EmailFromAddress` for `EditorFor` are standing out as potential causes for the behaviour we're seeing.

The painful part is the tag helper has a valid `ModelExplorer` instance via the `For` property. But there is no built in provision to provide it to the html helper.

As to the resolution, the obvious one seems to be to use `EditorFor` rather than `Editor` however it doesn't look easy. It'd likely involve reflection and building an expression.

Another option is, considering the tag helper resolves the `ModelExplorer` correctly, is to extend `HtmlHelper` and override the `GenerateEditor` method - what both `Editor` and `EditorFor` end up invoking - so you can pass in the ModelExplorer and work around the problem.

```
public class CustomHtmlHelper : HtmlHelper, IHtmlHelper
{
    public CustomHtmlHelper(IHtmlGenerator htmlGenerator, ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine, IModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, IViewBufferScope bufferScope, HtmlEncoder htmlEncoder, UrlEncoder urlEncoder) : base(htmlGenerator, viewEngine, metadataProvider, bufferScope, htmlEncoder, urlEncoder) { }

    public IHtmlContent CustomGenerateEditor(ModelExplorer modelExplorer, string htmlFieldName, string templateName, object additionalViewData)
    {
        return GenerateEditor(modelExplorer, htmlFieldName, templateName, additionalViewData);
    }

    protected override IHtmlContent GenerateEditor(ModelExplorer modelExplorer, string htmlFieldName, string templateName, object additionalViewData)
    {
        return base.GenerateEditor(modelExplorer, htmlFieldName, templateName, additionalViewData);
    }
}
```

Update your tag helper to use it:

```
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    if (context == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

    if (output == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));

    if (!output.Attributes.ContainsName(nameof(Template)))
    {
        output.Attributes.Add(nameof(Template), Template);
    }

    output.SuppressOutput();

    (_htmlHelper as IViewContextAware).Contextualize(ViewContext);

    var customHtmlHelper = _htmlHelper as CustomHtmlHelper;
    var content = customHtmlHelper.CustomGenerateEditor(For.ModelExplorer, For.Metadata.DisplayName ?? For.Metadata.PropertyName, Template, null);
    output.Content.SetHtmlContent(content);

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Finally register the new helper, the earlier the better I'd say

```
services.AddScoped<IHtmlHelper, CustomHtmlHelper>();
```

[Working solution](https://github.com/rgvlee/StackOverflow/tree/master/Question60078465/RazorPages)