# Client-Side Validation of Child Properties in MVC Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, tag-helpers, validationattribute

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 (C#) application, I have a class called Name:

```
public class Name
{
    public virtual string? First { get; set; }
    public virtual string? Middle { get; set; }
    public virtual string? Last { get; set; }
    public virtual string? Suffix { get; set; }
}
```

I also have several models containing a property (of type name) called NameFull:

```
[RequiredProps(nameof(Name.First), nameof(Name.Last))] // *** More about this in a minute. ***
public Name? NameFull { get; set; }
```

These model properties get used by a custom tag helper like this: `<field asp-for="NameFull" />`. There's logic inside the custom tag helper detects that the model property is a complex type and [generates a custom HTML helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60463058/5829140) since HTML helpers can [handle complex objects unlike tag helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078465/editorfor-tag-helper-doesnt-render-validation-attributes-when-using-fluentvalid). So basically this code `<field asp-for="NameFull" />` generates multiple input elements.  That's the background, here's my problem...

---

I want to be able to make *some* of those inputs required on a case-by-case basis. So maybe in one model first and last name are required. In another model, none of them are required. So I created a custom attribute named RequiredPropsAttribute (see model example above). It inherits from ValidationAttribute and implements IClientModelValidator [AttributeAdapter to apply client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#attributeadapter-for-client-side-validation) like so:

```
public sealed class RequiredPropsAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    //most of the logic has been omitted for brevity...
    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        var properties = context.ModelMetadata.Properties;
        if (!context.Attributes.ContainsKey("data-val"))
        {
            context.Attributes.Add("data-val", "true");
        }
        if (!context.Attributes.ContainsKey("data-val-required"))
        {
            context.Attributes.Add("data-val-required", $"The {string.Join(", ", properties)} fields are all required.");
        }
    }
}
```

This does allow me to add validation to the parent property (Name), but what I want is to apply the validation to its nested children.  In short, I want something similar to the above code that injects `data-val="true"` and `data-val-required="This field is required"` into the nested child inputs (Name.First, Name.Middle, Name.Last, Name.Suffix). I've tried accessing the children using `context.ModelMetadata.Properties`, but the collection isn't set up in such a way to where I can write code like this: `property.Attributes.Add("data-val", "true")`.  Which leads me to my question...

**QUESTION: How do I write logic inside AddValidation that lets me basically say: loop through the child properties of Name and add attributes to each of them so each child `<input>` gets `data-` validation attributes. Is this possible? And if not, is there any other way I can conditionally add a required attribute to the name properties based on attributes applied to name, e.g. add a RequiredIf to `First` that says "if Name has a RequiredProps attribute containing `First`, then make first required, etc.?**

Thanks in advance for your help, everyone!

Comment: Maybe this could help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367287/disable-required-validation-attribute-under-certain-circumstances/17067983

Comment: @Marcio Thanks for the reply - I'll look into it!

Comment: Hi @dhughes, did you find the solution?

Comment: Hi-ya.  Sorry it's been a while since I've logged on here.  No, I never did quite get anything to work the way I envisioned it.  What I ended up settling on was creating two different models: a RequiredNameModel and an OptionalNameModel and